# How to filter data in Angular 2 with checkboxes?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a list of tasks:

```
import { Task } from './tasks';

export const TASKS: Task[] = [
  { 
    taskCity: 'Tokyo', 
    taskName: 'Todo One',
    taskPrivacy: 'Personal',
    taskType: 'Night',
    taskDeadline: '13 Aug',
    taskPrice: '10 021 Р'
  },
  { 
    taskCity: 'Canberra', 
    taskName: 'Todo Two',
    taskPrivacy: 'Public',
    taskType: 'Day',
    taskDeadline: '23 Sept',
    taskPrice: '2 010 Р' 
  },
  { 
    taskCity: 'Jacksonville', 
    taskName: 'Todo Three',
    taskPrivacy: 'Personal',
    taskType: 'Night',
    taskDeadline: '30 Sept',
    taskPrice: '3 560 Р' 
  }
];
```

My filter code looks like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(tasks: any, term: any): any {
        if(term === undefined) {
            return tasks;
        }
        return tasks.filter(function(task: any) {
            return task.taskName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
        })
    }
}
```

And this list is output in a table:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" name="test" placeholder="Search">
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks | filter:term; let i = index"> 
   <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
   <td>{{task.taskCity}}</td>
   <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
   <td>{{task.taskType}}</td>
   <td>{{task.taskDeadline}}</td>
   <td>{{task.taskPrice}}</td>
</tr>
```

Everything works fine, but now I want to add two checkboxes: 'Privacy' and 'Type' to filter items by 'taskPrivacy' and 'taskType'. 
I've looked through [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/L8g6p9?p=preview) example and still can't adapt it.

Comment: Angular strongly discourages the use of pipes for filtering and sorting. [Doc here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this in a different way, and not with a Pipe.
Add something like this to your component:

```
get filteredTasks() {
        return this.tasks.filter(t => t.taskName.toLowerCase().includes(this.term.toLowerCase()); 
        // you can then extend this logic to include your new checkboxes easier that with a pipe
}
```

and then in your view template you just bind to this new property instead of tasks:

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of filteredTasks ; let i = index">
```